# Windows Phone Store - ARToolKit - Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, artoolkit

I have created a Windows Phone 8.1 application in Unity3D that uses ARToolKit for Augmented Reality. When testing the application store package created in Visual Studio 2015 in Windows App Certification Kit an error is displayed:

```
Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:
  This API is not supported for this application type - Api=arwAddMarker.Module=__internal.dll. File=Assembly-CSharp.dll.
  This API is not supported for this application type - Api=arwCapture.Module=__internal.dll. File=Assembly-CSharp.dll.
  This API is not supported for this application type - Api=arwGetARToolKitVersion. Module=__internal.dll. File=Assembly-CSharp.dll.
  This API is not supported for this application type - Api=arwGetBorderSize. Module=__internal.dll. File=Assembly-CSharp.dll.
  ... [and many more functions]
Impact if not fixed: Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Phone Store apps violates the Windows Phone Store certification requirements.
How to fix: Review the error messages to identify the API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Phone Store app. Please note, apps that are built in a debug configuration can fail this test as these environments may pull in unsupported APIs. Retest your app in a release configuration.
```

Googling for an hour gave me no answer to any question I could ask here. It almost looks like the problem does not exist or is not addressed by anyone.

Is there something I can do to publish this application to Windows Phone Store?